# Can't push to git because of large file

Tags: git, large-files

I have tried removing the file and clearing the cache. I've tried doing:
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -am 'git cache cleared'
git push

Any suggestions?

Writing objects: 100% (498/498), 1.04 GiB | 1.03 MiB/s, done.
Total 498 (delta 30), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (30/30), completed with 9 local objects.
remote: warning: File holidayGiftGuide/persona PSD mk/HP-Gift-Guide-persona Gaming.psd is 51.32 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File holidayGiftGuide/persona PSD mk/HP-Gift-Guide-persona Trending tech.psd is 50.20 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: f3f7098117f80ccde9d36073b68e6d2e
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File holidayGiftGuide/GiftGuide2016-PSDs.zip is 786.21 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: The article you sent had nothing to do with my issue..